How to reuse a model for different database frameworks?
Which is the best way to use a model definition with different databases? I have projects which share objects. The first uses an SQLite database, the second Entity Framework.
Object definition:
[Table("Members")]          <---- Specific attribute of SQLite
class Person
{

   [PrimaryKey]             <---- Specific attribute of SQLite
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   [Ignore]                 <---- Specific attribute of SQLite
   public int Age {get; set;}

}

If I want to reuse this definition I have to replace SQLite attributes with Entity Framework attributes. Should I create a BasePerson object:
class Person
{

   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public int Age {get; set;}

}

and derive sub-objects depending on database, overriding properties like:
using Sqlite;

[Table("Members")]
class PersonSqlite : Person
{

   [PrimaryKey]
   public override Guid Id {get; set;}


   [Ignore]
   public override int Age {get; set;}

}

using EntityFramework;

[Table("Members")]
class PersonEF : Person
{

   [Key]
   public override Guid Id {get; set;}


   [Ignore]
   public override int Age {get; set;}

}


I have to remove the Sqlite attributes and change them Why remove them? You can have more than one attribute. Just include the namespace to disambiguate any attributes with the same name. [Sqlite.PrimaryKey][EntityFramework.Key] public override Guid Id {get; set;}

When you say Sqlite, do you mean the SQLite-net library?

In EF, you can do without attributes on entity classes. The configuration of the models can be done using the fluent API.

You can use SQLite with EF (which is overkill, but if you are going to use both anyway ...) => SQLite EF Core Database Provider

@AlexanderPetrov yes, I'm using sqlite-net-pcl package to manage the database from android phone. Can I use the FluentAPI with this library ?

@AlexanderPetrov as far as I know the entity framework is not  recommended in mobile applications

don't sleep on Akavache on Android + Sqlite. If all you need is Key-Value (seems like that's not the case though), this is the best way

If you use entity framework to define your model, either using the fluent API or data annotations, you should be able to use the model with all supported databases, including SQLite. You should just need to change the database provider when configuring entity framework.
This is assuming all projects actually use entity framework, and not another ORM or completely different access method, like ADO.NET. If that is the case you could multiple properties on the same class, you just need to include the namespaces in the attribute:
[Sqlite.Table("Members")] 
[EntityFramework.Table("Members")]        
class Person

But this increases the risk for inconsistencies, if someone forgets one attribute or another. And may cause training issues when moving developers between projects. So I would probably recommend using the same database access method for all projects.
Do note that there may be some database specific features that will not work on other databases. But table names, keys, and ignore should be common for all databases.

The answer is Fluent API for configuration:
public class PersonEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore(b => b.Age);
    }
}

The Id will be picked up by convention. Plenty of things are configured by convention, I recommend to read up on that.
Most of this config will be universal for all databases. If you need to do something db specific, you can inject you IConfiguration and do something along the lines of:
if(configuration.IsPostgres()) 
{
    builder.DoSomethingPostgresSpecific();
}

if(configration.IsSqlLite())
{
    builder.DoSomethingSqliteSpecific();
}

The IsPostgres() and IsSqlite() don't exist - you have to figure out how to detect this. You can put DbKind property into you appSettings.json if you want to make it easier.
